# k3d no external ip for a service of load balanacer type

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, k3s

i am deploying the hello-world docker container to a k3d - cluster.
To get the external IP, a service of the type - load balancer is deployed.

After that i was hoping to call the appication via load balancer. But i don't get the external ip.

```
k3d create --name="mydemocluster" --workers="2" --publish="80:80"

export KUBECONFIG="$(k3d get-kubeconfig --name='mydemocluster')"

kubectl run kubia --image=hello-world --port=8080 --generator=run/v1
kubectl expose rc kubia --type=LoadBalancer --name kubia-http

export KUBECONFIG="$(k3d get-kubeconfig --name='mydemocluster')"
```

then  `kubectl get services`:
[image: 3d]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`LoadBalancer` type service will get external IP only if you use a managed kubernetes Service provided by cloud providers such as AWS EKS, Azure AKS, Google GCP etc.Tools such as k3d is for local development and if you create a `LoadBalancer` type service external ip will be pending. Alternative is to use NodePort type service or ingress . Here is the [doc](https://k3d.io/usage/guides/exposing_services/) on this.

Also you can use `kubectl port forward` or `kubectl proxy` to access the pod.

Comment: This solved my problem (I used NodePort and port-forward to expose my app). very straightforward explanation. Thanks. The doc link is no longer available though, This is the updated one (https://k3d.io/v5.4.6/usage/exposing_services/)

Answer (score 2):

I was following [this example](https://gitlab.com/nanuchi/youtube-tutorial-series/-/tree/master/demo-kubernetes-components)

with k3d and there it seems to work fine:

```
(base) erik@buzzard:~/kubernetes/tutorial> 
kubectl  get services 
NAME                    TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes              ClusterIP      10.43.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          3d6h
mongodb-service         ClusterIP      10.43.215.113   <none>        27017/TCP        27m
mongo-express-service   LoadBalancer   10.43.77.100    172.20.0.2    8081:30000/TCP   27m
```

As I understand, k3d is running k3s which is more of a full kubernetes setup than minikube for instance. I can access the service at http://172.20.0.2:8081 without problems.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your (late) answer. Could you add the `k3d`-command you've run to create the cluster? Sounds like you mapped the `NodePort` of this service with it. See https://k3d.io/usage/guides/exposing_services/#2-via-nodeport

Please add the necessary parts of the example you linked here. As an answer should be self-contained.

Comment: That example seems to use minikube. So I am not sure how relevant this is here.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a [cloud controller manager](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/cloud-controller/) to act as a service controller to do that.  As far as on-prem goes, your best option is likely [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/).

That being said, I don't know how that will behave with the underlying docker network in K3d.  It's on my list of things to try out.  If I find it works well, I'll come back and update this post.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing my manifest from a LoadBalancer type to an Ingress type.  K3d doesn't seem to expose external IP's properly to a load balancer type.

Oddly, I did find I was able to get the LoadBalancer type to work if I deployed really quickly.  It seemed it had to be after the master node was up and before any agents were up.